# SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name $name.storage.googleapis.com

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I want to run tensorflow traning script in google cloud ml. One of the buckets from an external project. I have created cloud ml engine service account and add it as an user to this external project.

After that, have executed the following command in my terminal with gcloud initialised project:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --my-service-acc-key.json
```

And then submit my job as:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training ..arguments
```

Job was submitted successfully and was running until accessing resources from external bucket with `file_io.FileIO('gs://external-bucket')`

I got the following error `SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host ${bucket-name}.storage.googleapis.com` instead.

Looks like something wrong with credentials, but can't find anything useful in documentation.

What could be a problem?

Comment: Could you confirm whether `${bucket-name}` was in the original error message or did you just replace the original bucket name with it for privacy reasons? If `${bucket-name}` was in the original error message, that probably means that you're trying to read an object from the bucket `${bucket-name}` which is not a real bucket, so there might be a bug with string substitution in your training Python code.

Comment: @AlexeySurkov Hi, bucket-name was replaced for security reason, but basically it's domain-name bucket, f.e. img.domain.com/pictures/.
Bucket is accessible and can be reached with gsutil, f.e `gsutil ls bucket-name` if an user auth as service account.
btw, I'm able to read from other bucket in the same project, which is not domain-name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately domain buckets like `bucketname.domainname.com` are not properly supported by the GCS client library inside TensorFlow at the moment.

This problem was fixed in the TensorFlow Google repository today.

The fix should become available on [TensorFlow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) within 2-3 days from now, after which you should be able to either build TensorFlow from head or take a [nightly Linux build](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/) and provide it as one of the package_uris when submitting a training job to Cloud ML Engine.

Alternatively you can wait until it gets picked up by the next official TensorFlow release supported by Cloud ML Engine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Providing package_uris during submition seems the most convenient.

Comment: The fix has reached github now:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/2ba27efa12283f5a87ea8d81bd75afc46813bd4d