# Tensorflow fileio reading from GCS bucket via Dataflow: SSL no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name

Tags: python, tensorflow, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am running a slightly modified version of the [cloudml flowers sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers) to classify my own images where I encounter a problem in the preprocess part. It seems when pointing to my own images which are in another project they can't be reached:

> > return pywrap_tensorflow.ReadFromStream(self._read_buf, length, status): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in **exit** self.gen.next() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status)) UnavailableError: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 0, error code 51, error message 'SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '$BUCKET.com.storage.googleapis.com'') when reading $BUCKET.com/image.jpg

(I've replaced the actual bucket name with $BUCKET).

I run the scripts from a vm where I've installed the required packages from the requirements.txt file:

> > apache-beam[gcp]==0.6.0
> >
> > pillow==4.0.0
> >
> > tensorflow==1.4.1

What I've tried/done so far:

- verified that I can run the original flowers preprocessing from the sample.sh file with no modifications
- changed access for the compute engine service account of the default project ("default-project-id"-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) to "Storage Object Viewer" for the project holding the bucket. The same has been done for the corresponding @cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
- verified that the path names to the images in bucket owned by the other project are right
- when reading from a bucket that *does not* have a .com name but still is in another project (with access to the compute engine service account of the other project also set to "Storage Object Viewer") a similar error is thrown, only it's now "PermissionDenied" instead of "Unavailable".
- with my default gcloud auth I am able to run the preprocess locally with no errors.

  > > python trainer/preprocess.py \
  > >      --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
  > >      --input_path $INPUT_PATH_EVAL \
  > >      --output_path $OUTPUT_PATH_EVAL \
- I've have looked at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044566/ssl-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches-target-host-name-name-stor/43082418#43082418), only that was an older version of tensorflow that should not be an issue with 1.4 and if that was the case I would probably still be able to reach the regular non-domain bucket which I am not.

So what am I missing with access between projects in running this example?

Comment: Maybe it is unrelated to the problem but you may want to use apache-beam 2.2. Otherwise, TF version on the DF service would be TF 1.0 (not 1.4.1) when any version older than apache-beam 2.0 is used.

Answer (score 2):

Google(TensorFlow) APIs do not support double wildcard format, e.g., `*.*.storage.googleapis.com`.  They just support one wildcard certificate e.g., `*.storage.googleapis.com` . In your case, when you use  "$BUCKET.com.storage.googleapis.com”, more than one identity of a given type is present in the certificate (e.g., more than one DNS name).  For more details please refer to [RFC standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt).

The Permission Denied Error was thrown due to the permission issue. So, in this case, you do not have enough access to the buckets of other projects but the service is available. For more information please refer to [Request Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints)
 and [Access Control Options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) documents.

The easiest solution is to copy your files into Google Storage via Google Cloud API and get the images from there.